# Datatable not returning correct index while paginating

Tags: laravel, datatable

Laravel datatable using server side pagination, when doing any action on the datatable the indexing changes not in the correct order.
The controller code is below

```
return Datatables::of($newsletters)
        ->editColumn('created_at', function($row) {
            return Carbon::parse($row->created_at)->format('d-m-Y');
        })
        ->rawColumns(['created_at'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

JS code :

```
if($('#admin_news_letters_view').length > 0) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $('#admin_news_letters_view').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('admin.news_letters.view') }}",
            columns: [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return i++;
                    }
                },
                {data: 'name'},
                {data: 'email'},
                {data: 'created_at'},
            ]
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index colum in the controller.
Controller :

```
   return Datatables::of($newsletters)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('created_at', function($row) {
                return Carbon::parse($row->created_at)->format('d-m-Y');
            })
            ->rawColumns(['created_at'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Js :

```
 if($('#admin_news_letters_view').length > 0) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#admin_news_letters_view').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('admin.news_letters.view') }}",
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'
                    },
                    {data: 'name'},
                    {data: 'email'},
                    {data: 'created_at'},
                ]
            });
        });
    }
```